# What is the future of FSIS?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, fastsearch

Since FSIS will no longer be cross platform and being ported to .net, will FSIS still have a future? Or will it be all under FS4SP (Fast Search for SharePoint)

Also I know FS4SP is supported virtualized, how about FSIS?

Thanks!

Comment: What about putting your question on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

From a fast consultant who has been recently showed some betas in Redmond at Microsoft I heard that the integration into sharepoint will be pushed to a point where FSIS is simply not needed anymore as all data will be put into and searched from your sharepoint installation.

There are very few companys buy a Microsoft ESP Standalone installation these days as solr and others are getting stronger by day.